# Apache WSASocket failed to open the inherited socket. (LMHOSTS disabled)

Tags: apache, xampp

```
[Thu Aug 09 11:20:30 2012] [notice] Child 4656: Child process is running
[Thu Aug 09 11:20:30 2012] [crit] (OS 10022)An invalid argument was supplied.  : Child 4656: setup_inherited_listeners(), WSASocket failed to open the inherited socket.
[Thu Aug 09 11:20:30 2012] [crit] Parent: child process exited with status 3 -- Aborting.
```

I have started getting this error unexpectedly. I dont believe I changed any conf files.

1. Are there are any temporary files I can reset in the apache installation? I have moved everything from /xampp/tmp
2. I have checked to see if localhost:80 is in use, I dont think this is the case.
3. I have reset netsh as specified here: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=31765

Please recommend steps to reset apache as I believe it is possible this is an issue caused by a orphaned PID or something of that nature as nothing has changed and I do unexpected shutdowns of my computer.

This is on Windows XP, apache httpd.exe version is 2.2.11.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port 443 was in use. Then magically ceased being in use. Then I guess perhaps netsh reset caused LMHOSTS to be enabled because I ended up with Local Connection being renamed to Local Connection 2 with LMHOSTS enabled. This is called magic.

Panda Media Booster was using 443.